# g++ cannot be found

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-12.04

I wrote a c++ program as follows,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
main()
{
int a,b,c;
cout<<"Enter two numbers"<<endl;
cin>>a>>b;
c=a+b;
cout<<"Sum of two numbers are"<<c;

}
```

and tried to compile the program with the following,

```
home$ g++ add.cpp
```

I get this error,

> The program g++ can be found in the following packages, g++, pentium-builder

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Isn’t the error message pretty self-explanatory? You need to install g++!

Comment: sudo apt-get install g++

Comment: No, use `sudo apt-get install build-essential` rather than just installing `g++`

Answer (score 8):

You need to install `g++`. As it suggests, it is found in the `g++` package, which you can install using `apt-get`. Something like:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

However, you might want to install `build-essential`, which basically gives you a lot of useful build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu's ditributions g++ is not installed by default. To install it, you should install "build-essentials" package.
You can find this package with GUI Package Manager or open a Terminal and write:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

Build-essentials contains many tools to compile, execute and debug native programs.